# When use redis for kvs, Which is speedy to use 1 db or different ones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, redis

I'm a developper using rails application to use redis.

I'm making some functions using redis by ruby now.

so, I have a quastion which is speedy to use redis 1db or multiple ones.
for example, I make a follow 2 functions with 2 gems.

- histories_function: using redis-objects
- counts_function:    using sidekiq

Which connection is better??

**to connect same db**

```
Redis::Objects.redis = Redis.new (host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379, db: 0)
Sidekiq.redis = Redis.new(host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379, db: 0)
```

or

**to connect different db**

```
Redis::Objects.redis = Redis.new (host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379, db: 0)
Sidekiq.redis = Redis.new(host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379, db: 1)
```

if you like ,please tell me the reasons with answer.
Thanks.

Comment: if you connect same db, you use own namespace for each of them.
that mean both connection wll not collide with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Redis' shared (numbered) databases only provide separate keyspaces - they are still managed by the same single process. This means that, in terms of performance, they are identical to using a single database.

The recommended approach, when you want to achieve and ensure maximal performance, is to use a dedicated Redis instance for each database. You can read more about this at: https://redislabs.com/blog/benchmark-shared-vs-dedicated-redis-instances

Comment: This is just the information I wanted!!
Thanks for you and your great product.